# How to disable or prevent going back form browser back button in react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using `react-router-dom` v6, and I've seen other people's questions, but they're not helpful to me; all I want is to make going back to any point impossible.

```
const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.userData);
  /* Destructuring the state of auth from the redux store. */
  const { isLogged, isVerified, resetPasswordSent, resetPasswordVerified } =
    useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const Check = () => {
    if (user?.firstTimeAccess === true) {
      return <SetProfile />;
    } else if (user?.firstTimeAccess === false) {
      return <Navigate to="/home" />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={isLogged ? <Check /> : <Landing />} />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={!isLogged ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/home" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/register"
          element={!isLogged ? <Register /> : <Navigate to="/home" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/home"
          element={isLogged ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
        >
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="chat" element={<Chat />} />
        </Route>

        <Route
          path="/join"
          element={meetingStarted ? <MeetingRoom /> : <Navigate to="/home" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/verify_account"
          element={!isVerified ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <VerifyAccount />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/auth/:authService/:socketId"
          element={<DesktopClientOauth />}
        />
        <Route path="auth/successful" element={<OauthSuccessfulPage />} />

        <Route
          path="/password_reset"
          element={!isLogged ? <ForgotPassword /> : <Navigate to="/home" />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/password_reset/verify_reset_code"
          element={
            resetPasswordSent ? <ResetPassword /> : <Navigate to="/home" />
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/password_reset/new_password"
          element={
            resetPasswordVerified ? <NewPassword /> : <Navigate to="/home" />
          }
        />

        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: With replace, like this <Navigate to="/your-path" replace />;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, or shouldn't, block or modify the browser's back button default behavior, but you *can* control navigation actions within your app. If you want to control back navigation actions within your app to prevent navigating back to a page you should basically ***not*** navigate forward and populate the history stack to make entries to navigate back to. In other words, use redirects instead of navigates, i.e. `REPLACE` actions instead of `PUSH` actions.

- Declarative navigation using `Navigate` component and the `replace` prop

  `<Navigate to="...." replace />`
- Declarative navigation using `Link` component and the `replace` prop

  `<Link to="...." replace>.....</Link>`
- Imperative navigation using `navigate` function and the `replace` option

  ```
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  navigate("....", { replace: true });
  ```